# Banach Algebras and closed ideals.

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis

according to Fourier analysis (namely Young's inequality), $L^1$ is a Banach algebra with the convolution operation. There are two results that I would like a reference for proofs. The first is that all ideals contained in $L^1$ (as an algebra) also have their $L^1$-closures as ideals. The second is that for fixed $f$, the smallest ideal closed ideal containing $f$ conincides with the smallest closed subspace containing all the translates of $f$.

Comment: 1. Since the ambient space here is $L^1$, the closure of any of its subset is in $L^1$. 2. By 'translations' do you mean scalar multiples $\lambda f$ of $f$?

Comment: Translations here means $\tau_yf(x)=f(x-y)$. So the ideal in 2. described would contain $(\tau_yf)_{y\in\mathbb{R}^n}$.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation for 1. Taking the closure of an ideal in $L^1$ (say $I$) we can get elements that need not be in $L^1$. We need to show that this cannot happen. i.e, this is a non-trivial result.

Comment: What is the ambient space then where the closure is taken?

Comment: Ah I see, there was a typo. The claim was that for all ideals in L^1, the closure is also an ideal. This is more interesting and I understand how to do this. Do you have any idea how to go about the second one?

Comment: Yes, we have $f(x-y)=f*\delta_y$ for the Dirac measure $\delta_y$ concentrated on $y$. There's a sequence of functions $g_n\in L_1$ that in some sense converges to $\delta_y$: namely let $g_n$ be nonnegative with support in $(y-\frac1n,\,y+\frac1n)$ and integral $1$. Then you need to prove $f*g_n\to f*\delta_y$.

Comment: hmm, could I bypass this by using approximate identities instead? Given an approximate identity $(\phi_t)_t$, I already have that $f*\tau_y(\phi_t)\to \tau_yf$ as $t\to 0$. This shows that smallest closed ideal generated by $f$ contains all the translates of $f$. However this won't prove minimality. Namely my ideal needs to be the smallest closed subspace as well.

Comment: Yes, it's the same as approximate identities. I think it's enough to prove that that closed subspace will be an ideal, and for that try to approximate $g*f$ by linear combinations of the translations of $f$.